# Rigorous Proof: Circle cannot be embedded into the the real line!

Tags: general-topology

Can somebody give rigorous proof that the circle cannot be embedded into the real line? Obviously, if so it must be necessarily continuous and I guess this suffices in this case since there is no continuous injection by intuition...

Comment: Hint: The sphere is a connected space which remains connected when removing one point.  Is the same true of any subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Got it - thx ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you’re asking for a proof that the sphere is not homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb R$. This is easy: the sphere is connected, and its image in the real line would be as well. But the only connected subsets of the line are the intervals. Whether open, closed, or half-and-half, any interval is disconnected by the removal of three points, but the sphere is not.

Comment: Oh, by sphere I actually meant the circle ...but the proof stays the same - thx ;)

Comment: Well, the circle *is* disconnected by the removal of two points. So the argument has to be changed. Instead, the image of the circle in the line is both connected and compact, thus a *closed bounded* interval, which can (by removing the endpoints) remain connected after the removal of two points. But the circle is *always* disconnected after the removal of two points.

Comment: Is there a general name or approach to show $S^n$ does not embed in $\mathbb R ^n$? Do we use ( top) homology?

Comment: Sorry @MSIS , you’ll have to ask somebody else for this information: I’m no topologist.

Answer (score 3):

**Theorem**: Any continuous map from an interval $[a,b]$ into $\mathbb R$ which is injective on $(a,b)$ takes distinct values on the endpoints.

This follows because all injective maps from an interval to $\mathbb R$ are strictly monotone by the intermediate value theorem.

Now an injective map of a circle into $\mathbb R$ can be thought of as a map of an interval where the endpoints map to the same value. By the previous theorem, this is impossible if the map is injective.

Comment: Do you know if there is a general name for the result that $S^n$ does not embed in $\mathbb R^n$ and if there is a general argument for all cases? Maybe using homology?

Comment: @MSIS I don't know if it has a name. It looks to me like you can use Alexander Duality to show that $S^n$ can't embed in $\mathbb R^n$. Not sure if that is an elementary enough proof for you. There may be easier ways.

Comment: Thank you. After a bit of searching, it seems Borsuk-Ulam does it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem

Comment: @MSIS ah of course. Thanks for the reference.