# Why do we consider here the torus as a subset of the complex numbers?

Tags: general-topology, complex-numbers, real-numbers

I'm solving the following exercise:

> Show that the n-dimensional Torus $\mathbb{T}^n\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ with i'ts subspace topology is a topological manifold of dimension $n$.

My question is not about how to solve the exercise, I'm only wondering why we take $$\mathbb{T}^n\subset \mathbb{C}^n$$ Wouldn't it work if we take $$\mathbb{T}^n\subset \mathbb{R}^n$$
Or is there another reason?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The unit circle naturally lives in the complex plane.

Comment: ah okei perfect thanks

Comment: Note also that $T^2 = S^1 \times S^1$ cannot possibly be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (nor is $T^1=S^1$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Sorry I don't get this point. So I know that $T^2$ is homeomorphic to $S^1\times S^1$ but I don't see why this is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Because it lives (at best) in $\mathbb{R}^3$:  it is impossible to draw/embed a doughnut on a flat sheet of paper.

Comment: see also:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728415/rigorous-proof-circle-cannot-be-embedded-into-the-the-real-line

Comment: oh yes sorry, but we have $T^2\subset \mathbb{C}^2$ which can be identified with $\mathbb{R}^4$ right?

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: ah perfect thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We usually define $\mathbb{T}^n$ as $\underbrace{S^1 \times S^1 \times \cdots \times S^1}_{n \text{ times}}$.  Since $S^1$ is a (topological) subspace of $\mathbb{C}$, the $n$-fold product $\mathbb{T}^n$ is naturally a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$, and not $\mathbb{R}^n$.  You could, however, identify $\mathbb{C}^n$ with $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ in the usual way and say that $\mathbb{T}^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{2n}$.  Note that requires doubling the dimension/superscript on the right.

In fact, it is a good exercise to prove this cannot possibly be right in low dimensions.  For example, $\mathbb{T}^1 = S^1$ cannot embed as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.  This is a straightforward connectedness argument.  Likewise, you can prove that the "standard" torus $\mathbb{T}^2 = S^1 \times S^1$ cannot embed as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but it can be realized in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is a dimension better than the above-described $\mathbb{C}^2 \cong \mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Ah so for the connectedness argument you spoke about. Is the following correct: Assuming that $S^1$ can be embedded as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ we can define a homeomorphism from $S^1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. But removing two points in $S^1$ leads to the fact that it isn't connected anymore. Nevertheless the image of this two line segments are still mapped to intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ which are clearly connected. This gives us a contradiction. Thus $S^1$ can not be embedded as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: That's not a contradiction:  when you remove two points from the circle the remaining two arcs will map to two intervals, but there is nothing wrong with disconnected sets mapping to disconnected sets.  If $S^1$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}$ then there is a **subspace** $X$ of $\mathbb{R}$ with a homeo $S^1 \to X$.  But $X$ must be compact and connected, so $X$ must be an interval $[a,b]$.  Hence $S^1$ is homeo to $[a,b]$, but this is a contradiction:  removing any single point of $S^1$ leaves a connected space, but that is false for $[a,b]$.

Comment: ah okei thank you.